# Returning "undefined" field in object

Tags: php, jquery, iphone, json, jquery-mobile

I'm having an issue where one of the fields in a created object is `undefined`.
Here's the object:

```
var Collateral = Collateral || {};

Collateral.NoteModel = function(config) {
"use strict";
this.loanId = config.loanId;
this.docId = config.docId;
this.borrowerName = config.borrowerName;
this.funder = config.funder;
this.docsDrawn = config.docsDrawn;
this.firstPayment = config.firstPayment;
this.loanAmount = config.loanAmount;
this.interestRate = config.interestRate;
this.dateDocsIn = config.dateDocsIn;
this.status = config.status;
this.eventDate = config.eventDate;
this.submittedBy = config.submittedBy;
};
```

I am storing a list of objects and each field of the object is storing properly, except the `status` field. When i call the `status` field by itself it returns the correct value, but when I try to access `note.status` it returns `undefined`.

Here is the code for creating the list of objects:

```
var renderNotesList = function(url, data, elementId, liFunc) {
    $.getJSON(url, data, function(response) {
        var notesList = [];
        renderNotesList.divider;
        $(elementId).empty();
        $(response).each(function() {
            var entry = $(this)[0];
            var note = new Collateral.NoteModel({ //initialize note object
                loanId: entry["Loan_ID"],
                docId: entry["Doc_ID"],
                borrowerName: entry["Borrower_Name"],
                funder: entry["Funder"],
                docsDrawn: entry["Docs_Drawn"],
                firstPayment: entry["First_Payment"],
                loanAmount: entry["Loan_Amount"],
                interestRate: entry["Interest_Rate"],
                dateDocsIn: entry["Date_Docs_In"],
                status: entry["Event_Type"],
                eventDate: entry["Event_Date"],
                submittedBy: entry["Submitted_By"]
            });
                    console.log(entry["Event_Type"]); // here the value is correct
                    console.log(note.status); // here the value is "undefined"
            var li = liFunc(note, renderNotesList.divider);         
            li.appendTo($(elementId));  

            try {
                $(elementId).listview('refresh');
            }
            catch(e) {
                return;
            }
        });
    });     
};
```

For all other `note.` calls, the variables are correct. It is only `status` that returns `undefined`. The objects were storing the correct values, but after a short while, without changing anything, the values became `undefined`. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `$(this)` instead of `$(this)[0]`, as it returns the same object.

Comment: Tried! It still returns undefined for the `status` field.

Comment: Ok, define `note` before `each` loop. Edit: never mind, as you mentioned `note.` for others work.

Comment: Tried. Still same result.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on jsfiddle? Messing around with code could lead to an answer ;)

Comment: does it work if you change to "_status"?

Comment: Try to invert the entry like this:
...
status: entry["Event_Date"],
eventDate: entry["Event_Type"],
...

Check if eventDate is undefined or if status is undefined.

Comment: It still does not work no matter what I change the name to.

Comment: Can you paste the response data here ?

Comment: So this is from the response. And this is the data that I want to use for `note.status`: `10:"Outstanding"`
but when I make a call to `note.status` it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Since I still can't comment I'll post as an answer. My guess here is that javascript has never been clear about the "passing as value/reference" issue. `var entry` contains all the values from your JSON and are copied as reference to your "note" object, but since it's on a limited scope, these references cease to exist.

Just for testing, try copying some of the values directly from the `response` variable.